# Term for Regional "Words per Minute"

Tags: psycholinguistics, spoken-language, speed

Is there a term for the variation in how many words per minute is spoken on average by people in various regions of the country/world?  A focus group mentioned they wished our Tech Support personnel spoke slower.

For example, let us say someone from California speaks substantially more words-per-minute than someone from Georgia.  I want to use this word, if there is one, as part of training manual for over-the-phone Tech Support personal.   I want the tech support personnel to pay attention to, and slow their speech down if necessary to match the words-per-minute rate of the customer.

Where I come from, calling people "fast-talkers" is a stereotype of a con man or unscrupulous salesman.  I am hoping there is a clinical word/term that can avoid any negative connotation of those who speak faster than others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term commonly used in linguistics appears to be [*tempo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_tempo). According to the book [*Innovative Presentations for Dummies*](https://www.dummies.com/careers/business-communication/creating-presentations/how-to-adjust-the-rate-of-speech-in-innovative-presentations/), other terms are *rate of speech*, *speed*, *pace* and *rhythm*.